# Create graphs quickly for pre-screeening

Tags: data-visualization, graphs

**Background:**
In my line of work we handle measuring files from different tests performed on mobile applications. We use HMGWin 3000 that produces binary .herf files, there is a software to read and analyze the data but it is limited in its uses as the X-axis is always time regardless of your need. Handling 30+ files to produce test-reports becomes a cumbersome and tedious task. The program can export .csv-files thankfully.

I need to pre-screen the testresults in order to know which files or measuring data that are meaningful to analyze further. But every test still needs a test report regardless if it was a success of failure.

**Question:**
Are there any programs that allow me to load .csv files and quickly export .png or .jpeg files? I know Excel allows .csv to be read and exported, but it still needs quite a few clicks to produce a viable graph.

I need something that produces an output quick, if it isn't dirty as well that's a huge plus.

**Edit:**
We use windows on the company computers, and I am looking for either open-source or commercial options. As long as the cost is not excessive I can swing it by the economy department.

Comment: Welcome Charlie.  What OS?  Are you looking for recommendations for gratis or commercial software?

Comment: I recently obtained a license for [Log Parser Lizard GUI](http://www.lizard-labs.com/log_parser_lizard.aspx). Commercial, though. Can read CSV and according their website (not tried myself yet) "You can use command line to automate the process". Drop me a comment and I'll elaborate in an answer if this tool might be something for you.